# PHP join two DB2 resource statements

Tags: php, sql, join, db2

I have two queries, with the same [group by] fields, but different (sum) calculation fields.

I want to either:

1. Add [Query #2] [Field 3] to
       [Query #1] [Field 4], for every
       record
2. Create a new array to later retrieve the
       data, which has [A1], [A2], [A3], [B4].

For both of these however, I need to know that records will be in exact same order.. maybe 'select' the record from the 2nd resource statement to join it to the original by all 3 key values.

```
$conn_resource = db2_connect ( "*LOCAL", "", "" );

$sql1 = "SELECT [A1], [A2], [A3], SUM([A4]) FROM [MyFile] WHERE [G] > 5 GROUP BY [A1], [A2], [A3] ";
$stmt1 = db2_prepare ( $conn_resource, $sql1 );

$sql2 = "SELECT [B1], [B2], [B3], SUM([B4]) FROM [MyFile] WHERE [G] > 5 GROUP BY [B1], [B2], [B3] ";
$stmt2 = db2_prepare ( $conn_resource, $sql2 );

if (! db2_execute ( $stmt1 ) || ! db2_execute ( $stmt2 )) {
   //failure
}

while ( $row = &db2_fetch_array ( $stmt1 ) ) {
    $sqlStatementTwoRow = db2_fetch_array ( $stmt2 );
    $row[4] = $row[3] + $sqlStatementTwoRow[4];
}
```

The above example should work, in theory, but i have no confirmation that the records from $stmt2 come in the exact same order as $stmt1.

---

**Edit**
The answer provided seems to be the solution, the more and more i migrate that solution into my real SQL statement.

I will post the full, live SQL which uses this idea, once i get it finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be better implemented inside the database as one statement that uses a correlated subquery to explicitly connect the outer result set to the inner result, and then compute the totals.

I'm not sure if the query below follows your business rules exactly, but hopefully this example will show you how you can coax more work out of a single SQL statement.

```
WITH outerquery ( a1, a2, a3, a4sum ) AS
( 
   SELECT a1, a2, a3, SUM( a4 ) FROM outerTable WHERE g > 5 GROUP BY a1, a2, a3 
)

SELECT o.a1, o.a2, o.a3, 
     o.a4sum + o.a3 + 
     ( SELECT SUM ( i.b4 ) FROM innerTable i 
       WHERE i.b1 = o.a1 AND i.b2 = o.a2 AND i.b3 = o.a3 AND g > 5
     ) AS totalaandb
FROM outerquery o
;
```

Comment: Is there something special about your 'o' alias, or did you forget to put it in?

Comment: Apologies...I forgot to add the o alias for outerquery. It's there now.